# What is the difference between elasticsearch index and searchkick reindex

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I am migrating from `elasticsearch` gem to `searchkick`.
Currently we are indexing a particular model by running.

```
Model.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
Model.import
```

In searchkick the documentation shows some other kind of indexing like:

```
Model.reindex
```

What is the difference between the former and the later?

Comment: searchkick internally uses elasticsearch gem. Model.reindex is how you should reindex after migration.